# Coordinate change for metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I am rather confused by the idea of "geodesic polar coordinates", so I hope someone would kindly explain it to me.

As far as my understanding goes, given a Riemannian metric $ds^2=E\,dx^2+2F\,dx\,dy+G\,dy^2$ we somehow have to find other variables $u,v$ so that $ds^2=du^2+G(u,v)\,dv^2$.

1. How can I convert $ds^2={dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2\over f(r)^2}$ where
   $f(r)$ is some function of $r$ into that form?
2. Is there an "algorithm" to achieve this change of form?
3. Is there some significant benefit in doing so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Geodesic polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$ are easy to define with exponencial map basic properties, only difference with normal coordinates $(u,v)$ is that you use polar coordinates in your domain. They are a simple change of variables like any others that you can define.

An algorithm is like any change of variables studied in multivariable calculus.

This change of variable to polar coordinates is very meaningful and give us some powerful theorems like the *Gauss lemma* (which say that $F(\rho,\theta)=0$).

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer and I have a question related. Is there a method to change $ds^2=E\,dx^2+2F\,dx\,dy+G\,dy^2$ to $ds^2=du^2+G(u,v)\,dv^2$? That is, how to find explicitly the coordinates $(u,v)$ as functions of $(x,y)$? Do you have some reference for that? Thanks!

Comment: I do not remember so much of differential geometry. But the books I used to read about this stuff were "Riemannian Geometry" and "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" both from M. Do Carmo.